# Set ImageRescource from a String value

Tags: android, android-imageview, android-drawable, android-resources

I have a String that Fetched from a XML file named `greece_ship`. and also i have an image file in `res/drawable` folder in my project. i wanna set an `ImageView` that get it's resource file from my `greece_ship` string. i tried this but it's not work:

```
String image =  "R.drawable." + tour.getImage();
int res = Resources.getSystem().getIdentifier(image, "drawable", String.valueOf(Drawable.class));
vPic.setImageResource(res);
```

my next try is this  `String image =  tour.getImage();`  in line 1 Instead of `String image =  "R.drawable." + tour.getImage();`, but it's not work yet. help me please. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`greece_ship.png` is probably not part of   android, but it is something you added to the res/drawable, so you should use `getResources().getIdentifier` , and not `Resources.getSystem().getIdentifier`. The first parameter is the drawable's name. Just the name, and your case is the result of  `tour.getImage()`, without prepending anything. The third parameter is the package name. You can get it using `getPackageName()`. In the end it should look like:

```
int res = getResources().getIdentifier(tour.getImage(), "drawable", getPackageName());
```

assuming that you have a context to access the resources and `tour.getImage()` returns the `drawable`'s name without extension

Comment: I used  that `Resources.getSystem()` becase these codes are in this  `public class TourAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<TourAdapter.TourViewHolder>` class. and this class can't resolve `getPackageName()` too @Blackbelt

Comment: You need a context object for both. You can try using the view's context